# How to not overwrite and delete moved file

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm moving file `A` from directory `C` to directory `B` by `hg move C B`. In the directory `B` there's already file called `A`.

How can I tell to mercurial not overwrite the already existing in `B` file and mark the file as moved (delete the ile in `C`)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete file A from directory C.
2. Tell Mercurial that you already moved the file using [`hg rename`](https://selenic.com/hg/help/rename) from the command line:

   ```
   hg rename --after C/A B/A
   ```